# How to Get Latest Updated Record in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written query but I'm not getting latest updated data. I mean I have psn update column , I want current positiondata of latest updated date , according to "latestpsnupdate" I need currentposition.

```
SELECT 
     k.KeyWord,
     pa.UserName,
     pa.ProjId,
     k.KeywordID,
     kp.currentposition,
     kp.PsnUpdateDate
FROM Tbl_ProjAssignment pa 
INNER JOIN Tbl_keywords k on k.KeywordID=pa.KeywordID 
INNER JOIN seo.Tbl_KeywordPosition kp 
ON kp.keywordid = pa.keywordid   
WHERE k.ProjId='105' ORDER BY PsnUpdateDate DESC
```

o/p

```
keyword        UserName ProjId   keywordid currentposition  PsnUpdateDa
ventis123       Tester    105     1453          6            2015-03-11 
ventis123       krishna   105     1453          6            2015-03-11
annuity         Tester    105     1449          8            2015-01-30 
annuity         Tester    105     1449          7            2015-01-27 
ventissitnev    Tester    105     1452          6            2015-01-16 
annuity         Tester    105     1449          55           2015-01-15 
annuity         Tester    105     1449          6            2015-01-08 
annuity         Tester    105     1449          10           2014-12-13
```

o/p needed

desired o/p

```
keyword      UserName ProjId   keywordid currentposition  PsnUpdateDa
ventis123     Tester    105     1453        6              2015-03-11 
annuity       Tester    105     1449        8              2015-01-30
ventissitnev  Tester    105     1452        6              2015-01-16 
annuity       Tester    105     1449        55             2015-01-15
```

Comment: which database `mysql` or `sql-server`

Comment: use `group by` `keyword`

Comment: where to add group by keyword can u tell me please ?

Comment: in ms sql server . im writting query

Comment: select    k.KeyWord,pa.UserName,pa.ProjId,k.KeywordID,kp.currentposition,kp.PsnUpdateDate
 from Tbl_ProjAssignment pa 
inner join Tbl_keywords k on k.KeywordID=pa.KeywordID 
inner  join seo.Tbl_KeywordPosition kp on  kp.keywordid= pa.keywordid
  where k.ProjId='105'   group  by k.KeyWord order by PsnUpdateDate desc ...i have written like this but giving error

Comment: You want the latest PsnUpdateDate for each what? "annuity" appears twice in the keyword column, "6" appears twice in the currentposition column. From the question we can't tell what you want to group on.

Comment: i want the currentposition based on latest PsnUpdatedate for each keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as follows:

```
;WITH    CTE
AS ( SELECT k.KeyWord ,
            pa.UserName ,
            pa.ProjId ,
            k.KeywordID ,
            kp.currentposition ,
            kp.PsnUpdateDate ,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY k.keyword ORDER BY kp.PsnUpdateDate DESC ) AS positiondata
    FROM     Tbl_ProjAssignment pa
            INNER JOIN Tbl_keywords k ON k.KeywordID = pa.KeywordID
            INNER JOIN seo.Tbl_KeywordPosition kp ON kp.keywordid = pa.keywordid
    )

SELECT  *
FROM    CTE
WHERE   ProjId = '105'
        AND positiondata = 1
```

Comment: im getting eror "Invalid column name 'keyword'." can u check once please ?

Comment: as you didn't bring a proper schema so its confusing. but see edited one

Comment: i got the solution thanks . little chage done at partition by keywordid instead of keword

Comment: thanks both are working which one i willl use ? edited or previous one @mostafa ?

Comment: both of them are acceptable . second one uses CTE which looks newer and mote neat

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, If you'll put `GROUP BY`, be sure that ungroup fields are in an `AGGREGATE`. See my answer below:

```
SELECT 
     k.KeyWord,
     MAX(pa.UserName)UserName,
     pa.ProjId,
     k.KeywordID,
     kp.currentposition,
     MAX(kp.PsnUpdateDate)
FROM Tbl_ProjAssignment pa 
INNER JOIN Tbl_keywords k on k.KeywordID=pa.KeywordID 
INNER JOIN seo.Tbl_KeywordPosition kp 
ON kp.keywordid = pa.keywordid   
WHERE k.ProjId='105' 
GROUP BY k.keyword,pa.ProjId,k.KeywordID,kp.currentposition
ORDER BY kp.PsnUpdateDate DESC
```

Comment: error- "Column "seo.Tbl_KeywordPosition.PsnUpdateDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Row_number we can approach like this also ..just an sample example

```
    declare @t table (Keyword varchar(10), UserName  varchar(10),ProjId    int,keywordid int,perdate date   )
    insert into @t(Keyword,UserName,ProjId,keywordid,perdate)values ('ventis123','Tester',105,1453,'2015-03-11')
    insert into @t(Keyword,UserName,ProjId,keywordid,perdate)values ('ventis123','Tester',105,1453,'2015-03-11')
    insert into @t(Keyword,UserName,ProjId,keywordid,perdate)values ('annuity','Tester',105,1449,'2015-01-30')
    insert into @t(Keyword,UserName,ProjId,keywordid,perdate)values ('annuity','Tester',105,1449,'2015-01-27')

select DISTINCT tt.Keyword,
tt.UserName,
tt.ProjId,
t.Keyword,
t.perdate 
from  @t tt
    INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT MAX(keywordid)Keyword, 
                 MAX(perdate)perdate 
                 from @t 
             GROUP BY Keyword,UserName,ProjId )t
           ON t.Keyword = tt.keywordid  
          AND t.perdate = tt.perdate
          ORDER BY 1 desc
```